# Lazily generate Excel document in Java in chunks

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, stream-processing

I'm looking for a way to generate very large Excel documents (on the fly) in a streaming fashion *without* holding too much intermediary state in-memory (and preferably not on disk either). What I have is a lazy stream of data, `Stream<Data>`, potentially containing hundreds of thousands of `Data` objects. I want to continuously convert this data stream into excel rows written to an `OutputStream`. The end goal is *not* to write the Excel document to disk, I want to stream it through to an HTTP response.

I've tried using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) (4.0.0) but the problem with POI and its [SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) is that you can only write to the `OutputStream` once! I.e. this won't work:

```
OutputStream os = ..
Stream<Data> dataStream = ...
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();
partition(dataStream, 100)
     .peek((List<Data> data) -> addRow(sh, data))
     .forEach(__ -> wb.write(os));
```

What I try to do here is to partition the data stream (`Stream<Data>`) into chunks of 100 and then call the `addRow` method (not shown here) which converts the data into an Excel row and writes it to the `Sheet` (called `sh`). This actually ought to work fine if it weren't for the fact that `wb.write(..)` throws an exception when it's called the second time (i.e. when we reach the second chunk):

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:221)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SheetDataWriter.beginRow(SheetDataWriter.java:213)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SheetDataWriter.writeRow(SheetDataWriter.java:203)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.flushOneRow(SXSSFSheet.java:1876)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.flushRows(SXSSFSheet.java:1851)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.flushRows(SXSSFSheet.java:1865)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.flushSheets(SXSSFWorkbook.java:949)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.write(SXSSFWorkbook.java:923)
```

I've tried various hacks such as:

```
OutputStream os = ..
Stream<Data> dataStream = ...
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();
partition(dataStream, 100)
     .peek((List<Data> data) -> addRow(sh, data))
     .forEach(__ -> {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    wb.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
                    outputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
                });
```

But this doesn't seem to work either. I could of course just do something like this:

```
OutputStream os = ..
Stream<Data> dataStream = ...
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();
dataStream.forEach(row -> addRow(sh, row));
wb.write(os);
```

But the problem with this approach is that the entire Excel document is created (and temporarily stored on disk) before the first bytes are pushed to the `OutputStream`. This means that the `OutputStream` consumer needs to wait unnecessarily long before the data even begins to stream.

So my questions is: How can I generate an Excel document with very large set of rows *in chunks* without waiting for the entire document to be generated first?

Note that Apache POI is not a requirement and I'm happy to switch to another library if necessary.

Comment: Swap to a streamable format like CSV? Excel files have forwards-and-backwards references in them that make a pure stream-as-you-generate approach at best super super tricky, and impossible in many situations...

Comment: Unfortunately an actual Excel file is required :(

Comment: You're going to have to change one part of your requirements then, or spend a man-month or so writing Java code for Excel files...

Comment: A `*.xlsx` file is nothing else than a `ZIP` archive containing the rows of a sheet in a `/xl/worksheets/sheet*.xml` file in that archive. You wants streaming that `*.xlsx` file content through to an HTTP response. So your requrement is streaming the rows into a substream to `/xl/worksheets/sheet*.xml` within the main stream of the `*.xlsx` file content. Possible? Not that I was aware of. You could streaming the data through to an HTTP response and then creating the `*.xlsx` file on client side from that data. But `CSV` would not be my favorit for streaming the data. My favorit would be `XML`.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this. I guess this is why I haven't found any libraries that supports it. Maybe this even answers the question?